# Bootstrap in Express-NodeJS-images not showing

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load some images in the browser using bootstrap in Express(Handlebars), and although rest of the media contents appear fine , the images are not getting  loaded in the Browser(Chrome).

The code in the .hbs file is as follows:

```
  1 <div class="panel panel-default">
  2         <div class="panel-heading">     
  3                 <h2 class="panel-title">{{index.title}}</h2>    
  4                 <div>
  5                         <ul class="media-list">         
  6                                 {{#each movies}} <li class="media">
  7                                 <a class="pull-left" href="#"   
  8                                         <img class="media-object img-responsive" src= {{ poster_path }} alt=" ">
  9                                 </a>                            
 10                                 <div class="media-body">{{ title }}<br/><strong class="media-heading">{{ popularity }}</strong>
 11                                 </div>                          
 12                                 </li>                           
 13                                 {{/each}} </ul>                 
 14                 </div>
 15         </div>
 16 
 17 </div>
```

Here is a screen shot of the page:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0oBZ2pgT9DUQldkaHFfNllFblU/view?usp=sharing

Any comments/suggestions would be much appreciated.

ADDED FIDDLE :
https://jsfiddle.net/chattes/9azgfxex/

Thanks

Comment: Missing quotes from src attribute of img tag, use this instead:
<img class="media-object img-responsive" src="{{ poster_path }}" alt="">

Comment: That did not work and anyway I am using handlebars and i dont think we need quotes as i am doing data binding with {{ }}..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out... it was a mistake with the div tags.
Latest fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/chattes/9azgfxex/

```
<title>{{title}}</title>

<body>
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <h1><a href="/">discoverMovie</a></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <ul class="media-list">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <li class="media">
            <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" alt="Interstellar" width="200" height="100" class="img-thumbnail">
            <div class="media-body">"Interstellar"
              <br/><strong class="media-heading">14.524256</strong>
            </div>
          </li>
           </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <li class="media">
            <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg"
```